# How to link a program in C++

Tags: c++

My code is:

#### test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/bind.hpp>
#include "extern.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
int fun(int x,int y){return x+y;}
/*
 *void add(int &m,int &n);
 */
int main(){
    int m=1;int n=2;
    cout << m << "  "<< n << endl;
    add(m,n);
    cout << m << "  "<< n << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

#### extern.h:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/bind.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
void add(int &n,int &m);
```

#### extern.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/bind.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

extern int m;
extern int n;

void add(int &n,int &m) {
    n = n+1;
    m = m+1;
}
```

When I compile it with

```
g++ -Wall -o test test.cpp
```

It turns out to be:

```
/tmp/ccMHVRNo.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `add(int&, int&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But when I compile it with:

```
g++ -Wall -o test test.cpp extern.cpp
```

It works well:

```
$ ./test
1  2
2  3
```

So the reason is that `test.cpp` can't find the implementation of the `add()` function.

But I have added `extern.h` to `test.cpp`, why does it still say "undefined reference to `add(int&, int&)`"?

Comment: add `#include "extern.h"` to extern.cpp

Comment: Please don't `using namespace std;` or `boost` in a header file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721

Comment: @aschepler Those comments are less useful than the 'don't parse HTML with regex' ones that come up all the time. It's a bad practice, but we can safely assume that this is simply an example used for brevity.

Comment: I wouldn't have said anything if it was just in the *.cpp files.  In this example, there's no reason for the header to have any `using` statements at all (or `#include`s, for that matter).

Comment: aschepler,yeah ,you are right, this file is just modifed from extern.cpp,so I didn't delete the #include s. so after I add "extern.h" to extern.cpp,it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header file `extern.h` only tells your program how the **prototype** of the function is made. The linker needs the actual implementation of the function, so it looks for the code `add(int&,int&)` references to, and it cannot find it unless you give to the compiler all the files it needs (in this case, `extern.cpp` is the file the linker needs when looking for the `add` function).

Comment: so I should tell linker about the implememtation of the function.

Comment: you just need to pass the files containing the implementation of the functions you're using to the compiler. you need to pass `extern.cpp` otherwise the linker (which is summoned by `g++`) won't find the implementation of the `add` function anywhere.

Comment: I think add #include "extern.h" to extern.cpp  should work,but it's not

Comment: no, including `extern.h` in `extern.cpp` only copies _word by word_ what's written in `extern.h` inside `extern.cpp`, at the point you included it, and it's a preprocessor directive, so it's executed before compilation starts. I suggest you look at some tutorials or questions on this site about how compilation with multiple files works.

Comment: yeah,it seems I have big misunderstand of multiple files program. :-(

Comment: so the solution is to add exter.cpp to compiler or write a makefile.right?

Comment: short answer: yes. you need to understand what the compiler does and what's happening during compilation if you want a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of the function `void add(int&,int&)` is in the source file extern.cpp. The compiler can't know that this files is related to the program until you tell it.

You must specify all source files at the command line:

```
g++ -Wall -o test test.cpp extern.cpp
```

If you want to avoid compiling of all source files you can also specify the already compiled object file:

```
g++ -Wall -o test test.cpp extern.o
```

When you don't want to think every time what commands you need to compile you should use make and create an `Makefile` with rules that define how the target is build. with the makefile you can just start

```
make
```

and get the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual formula:

```
g++ -Wall -c test.cpp
g++ -Wall -c extern.cpp
g++ -o test test.o extern.o
```

There are one-liners, but those don't scale so well to larger projects.

Comment: You need some `-c` in there.